# Best workflow and practices for releasing a new python package version on github and pypi

Tags: python, git, github, pypi

I was wondering what is the best procedure or practices for releasing a new python package version on pypi and github.

For example, is this the typical workflow a major python package would follow?

1. On `master` branch, increment `version` number

   1. Set `version='1.5.0'` in `setup.py`
   2. Set `__version__ = '1.5.0'` in package `__init__.py`
2. Update `CHANGELOG.md` with new version
3. Run `tox` locally to verify package
4. Push changes `git push origin master`
5. Create tag `git tag v1.5.0 -m "Release v1.5.0"`
6. Push tag `git push origin v1.5.0`
7. Wait for `Travis CI` build to finish.
8. Build package `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
9. Verify created packages

   1. `test-sdist/bin/pip install dist/<package>-1.5.0.tar.gz`
   2. `test-wheel/bin/pip install dist/<package>-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
10. Upload to `PyPI Staging`

    1. `twine upload -r testpypi dist/<package>-1.5.0*`
    2. `pip install --user --no-cache-dir --extra-index-url https://testpypi.python.org/pypi <package>`
11. Upload to `PyPI Production`

    1. `twine upload dist/<package>-1.5.0>*`
    2. `pip install <package>==1.5.0`

Comment: I think you mean PyPI, the package index, not PyPy, the alternate Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the workflow is ok. I will try to turn it more clear and turn it a bit more generic:

1. On the master branch, increment the version number:

   - Set `version='1.5.0'` in `setup.py`
   - Set `__version__ = '1.5.0'` in the package `__init__.py`
2. Update `CHANGELOG.md` with the new version details.
3. Run tests locally to verify the package (use `tox` or other test tools).
4. Commit and push changes:

   ```
   git commit -am "Bump version to 1.5.0"
   git push origin master
   ```
5. Create and push a tag for the new release:

   ```
   git tag v1.5.0 -m "Release v1.5.0"
   git push origin v1.5.0
   ```
6. Wait for the Continuous Integration (CI) build to finish (e.g., Travis CI, GitHub Actions).
7. Build the package:

   ```
   python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
   ```
8. Verify the created packages:

   ```
   test-sdist/bin/pip install dist/<package>-1.5.0.tar.gz
   test-wheel/bin/pip install dist/<package>-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   ```
9. Upload to PyPI Staging (TestPyPI):

   ```
   twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/<package>-1.5.0*
   pip install --user --no-cache-dir --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ <package>
   ```
10. Verify that the package installs and works correctly from TestPyPI.
11. Upload to PyPI Production:

    ```
    twine upload dist/<package>-1.5.0*
    ```
12. Test the installation from PyPI Production:

    ```
    pip install <package>==1.5.0
    ```